# How do I get all possible combinations (not permutations) from two different arrays in Perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, variables, combinations, element

Say I have these two arrays:

```perl
my @varA = ("a","b"); # all possible values of varA
my @varB = (1,2); # all possible values of varB
```

and I want to get the output variable combinations:

```perl
varA = a, varB = 1; # the first possible combination
varA = a, varB = 2;
varA = b, varB = 1;
varA = b, varB = 2; # the last possible combination
```

I looked into the `Algorithm::Combinatorics` and related modules, but I can only see examples where they are used to get combinations of elements from a *single* array.

Is there a simpler way to do this than nested loops?

Edit:
For the sake of completeness, I have a number of `keys`, named variables, that can take on one of a number of possible values. I need to generate all combinations of each possible `key=value` pair with each other (not repeating the same key - each combination only has unique keys).

**Let's say I have the following attribute keys:**

```perl
ShoeSize # can be one of a set of size values
CurrentAge # can be any integer from 0 up to, say, 110 years
HeightInCm # can be any integer up to, say, 200 (2m tall!)
```

Now let's say I am studying statistics and I want to generate every combination of ShoeSize, HeightInCm and CurrentAge, then start counting how many people match each combination of values (ignore the counting bit, though - that is just for this illustration - there will only be one instance of each of my real combinations).

I am storing each Combination as a '3-key hash' within an array (the references, that is, each pointing to an instance of the same anonymous hash *set*).

**Example Output:**

```perl
@AoH = (
  [ # element 0
    {
      ShoeSize=10,
      CurrentAge=14,
      HeightInCm=150
    }
  ],
  [ # element 1
    {
      ShoeSize=12,
      CurrentAge=23,
      HeightInCm=172
    }
  ],
  [ # element 2
    {
      ShoeSize=8,
      CurrentAge=64,
      HeightInCm=167
    }
  ],
  [ # element 3
    {
      etc.
    }
  ]
)
```

How to generate this array of combination hashes with the correct set of unique keys is the real question.

Comment: "Simpler than a nested loop"? You mean simpler than `for my $varA (@varA) { for my $varB (@varB) { print "varA = $varA, varB = $varB" }`? I think you will struggle to find something simpler than that.

Comment: https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=817521

Comment: @TLP Granted, my example is simple. My real code has 10-15 levels and many optional values per level. This a product problem. I broke it down for ease of explanation.

Comment: What kind of output do you want -- list of combined values like `(a1, b1, a2, b2)`, or some strings formed with both like what you show ... ?

Comment: @skeetastax Well, try not to simplify too much. We get all sorts of skill level on questions here.

Comment: @zdim Thanks...yeah, not that simple, actually. These are in fact meant to be `key=value` pairs, and thinking more about it I don't think this will be easy to achieve without nested loops because I have to combine the values with the appropriate keys. E.g. combi1 = `k1=a; k2=1;`, combi2 = `k1=b; k2=1;`, combi3 = `k1=a; k2=2;`, combi4 = `k1=b; k2=2;`

Comment: @skeetastax  OK.  Just explain it well and we'll figure it out. I don't see what you mean exactly -- what are `k1` and `k2`?  (And where do they come from?) You got `a`,`b` and `1`,`2` in the two arrays (`@varA` and `@varB`) but I don't get the rest. Can you show a specific and precise example of what you need?

Comment: @skeetastax  "_combine the values with the appropriate keys_" -- do you mean that elements of one array are keys, and elements of the other are values, but they need be paired in some specific way? Or what? If the example from the question is too simple to demonstrate then can you enlarge it (just) enough to show exactly what you need? (With the specific output.) I'm curious now...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) you seem to be asking about.

There are libraries for that, like [Set::CrossProduct](https://metacpan.org/pod/Set::CrossProduct) and [Math::Cartesian::Product](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::Cartesian::Product).<sup>†</sup> The first one provides a generator, that can be used in a variety of ways, the second one produces the whole result list at once, which can be filtered.

It is not clear to me how you'd like to combine the elements from two sets (lists) -- concatenate values? form tuples? strings?  Please clarify and I can add specific examples, if needed.

Also note that in principle that can be just a double `map` or such

```
my @cp = map { my $e = $_; map { $_ . $e } @ary2 } @ary1;
```

(here the elements are concatenated)

---

**Edit**   A complete example has been added to the question, clarifying it. Here is one way for it, using a module for a cross product of three arrays (a triple-`map` would be a little unsightly).

The desired output described in the question is built inside the code block available for that.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';
use Data::Dump qw(dd);

use List::Gen qw(cartesian);

my @shoe_size = (8,10);     # (apologies to all "other" people...)
my @curr_age  = (21, 40);
my @height_cm = (170, 200);

# Returns a generator
my $gen = cartesian { 
    { shoe_size => $_[0], curr_age => $_[1], height_cm => $_[2] } 
} 
\@shoe_size, \@curr_age, \@height_cm;
    
my @combs = @$gen;  # Now this is an array of hashrefs

dd \@combs;
```

One can use any other method to form the cartesian product instead,<sup>‡</sup> and built that hashref out of each combination.

The code above prints

```
[
  { curr_age => 21, height_cm => 170, shoe_size => 8 },
  { curr_age => 21, height_cm => 200, shoe_size => 8 },
  { curr_age => 40, height_cm => 170, shoe_size => 8 },
  { curr_age => 40, height_cm => 200, shoe_size => 8 },
  { curr_age => 21, height_cm => 170, shoe_size => 10 },
  { curr_age => 21, height_cm => 200, shoe_size => 10 },
  { curr_age => 40, height_cm => 170, shoe_size => 10 },
  { curr_age => 40, height_cm => 200, shoe_size => 10 },
]
```

I place hashrefs directly in one array, but if desired output indeed needs each to be a sole element of an arrayref, as shown in the question, that is easy to modify.

The order of hash(ref) elements in printing can be sorted as desired.  For simplicity I use plain arrays for each data set and then hard-code their names in the output; this can be avoided by arranging data suitably.

One clear option is to use a hash for all data, so that each set has a label, for which we can then provide a sorting order.  This has another benefit: we can then list the names in their desired order at one place in the program.  Let me know if an example would be useful.

---

<sup>†</sup> There is more out there.  For one, if you can anyway make use of higher-order tools then definitely check out the mesmerizing [List::Gen](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Gen), which also provides a [cartesian](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Gen#cartesian-%7BCODE%7D-LIST) function.  The module hasn't been touched in a decade but it's all pure Perl so you can  use [its source](https://metacpan.org/dist/List-Gen/source/lib/List/Gen.pm) for things of interest.

---

<sup>‡</sup> Examples using other tools to build the product

**With `Set::CrossProduct`**

```
use Data::Dump qw(dd);

use Set::CrossProduct; 
    
my $cp = Set::CrossProduct->new( { # can give them names
    shoe_size => \@shoe_size,
    curr_age  => \@curr_age,
    height_cm => \@height_cm
} );

# Generator ($cp object) is ready

my $combs = $cp->combinations;  # all combinations at once

dd $combs;
```

The generator can be used to iterate over combinations one at a time as well. It has a small and nicely chosen set of functionalities for its generator.

**With `Math::Cartesian::Product`**

```
use Data::Dump qw(dd);

use Math::Cartesian::Product;

my @cp = map { 
        { shoe_size => $_->[0], curr_age => $_->[1], height_cm => $_->[2] } 
    }
    cartesian { 1 } \@shoe_size, \@curr_age, \@height_cm;

dd $_ for @cp;
```

The function `cartesian` returns an array with arrayrefs, each with elements in a combination, of all combinations for which the block `{...}` returns true. (The block is just a filter, but is compulsory in the syntax.)

Then that is passed through a `map` to format for the desired output.

Comment: `map` may possibly be an option...but only if I can maintain the `k=v` pairs as mentioned in my comment above. I do need to understand how to use `map` properly. Thx.

Comment: @skeetastax  Can do any and every thing with members of each pairing (one from `@ary1` the other from `@ary2`), whatever you want. Both with `map` and with functions from modules.  Can you explain what precisely you need? I don't understand that comment (see my response to it). Add an example to the question? (Just add the precise output you need from those two arrays in the question.)

Comment: Edited question with more complete example showing the result structure I am after. Thanks.

Comment: @skeetastax Ah, thank you! I get it ... will write it up now

Comment: @skeetastax Posted ... will edit further now but this should already be it?

Comment: Very nice indeed! Thank you. (I'm sure all the "other" people won't mind...wait, this is 2021...hmmm, maybe they will 8-/ )

Comment: Sadly, cpan fails to install `List::Gen` :(

Comment: @skeetastax Hum? Oh :(  I'll amend the answer with another tool used as well, as i get a minute...

Comment: @skeetastax Added examples of use for the two other libraries mentioned

Comment: you are an awesome person.

Comment: @skeetastax  Oh ... thank you :))  But please also tell me if it actually doesn't work in some way :)

Answer (score 1):

```perl
use Algorithm::Loops qw( NestedLoops );

my $iter = NestedLoops([ \@varA, \@varB ]);
while ( my ($varA, $varB) = $iter->() ) {
   say "varA = $varA, varB = $varB;";
}
```

or

```perl
use Algorithm::Loops qw( NestedLoops );

NestedLoops(
   [ \@varA, \@varB ],
   sub {
      my ($varA, $varB) = @_;
      say "varA = $varA, varB = $varB;";
   }
);
```

Comment: Thanks @ikegami. I could conceivably generate arrays of hashes, each hash containing a single `key=value` pair, do that for all my keys (such that I have 1 array per named key), then run the above on the AoHs, right? I think that would give me the unique combinations of `key=value` pairs, would it not?

Comment: You can do whatever you want with $varA and $varB